# debian bind load zone permission denied

Tags: linux, dns, permissions, bind, debian-buster

I have bind9 installed on Debian 10. It can't load created zone xxx.yy with error: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/db.xxx.yy failed: permission denied

/etc/bind/zones is mounted to fresh partition (fstab):
UUID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX        /etc/bind/zones     ext4    defaults        0       2

permissions (ls -la /etc/bind/zones/):
-rw-r--r-- 1 root bind  385 apr 30 07:48 db.xxx.yy

if I move zone files to location /etc/bind/ error disappear

Comment: Do you see any corresponding `dmesg` log entries? What are the permissions of the (mounted) `/etc/bind/zones` directory itself?

Comment: permissions of the (mounted):
drw-r--r--  2 root bind 4096 apr 30 07:48 zones

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> permissions of the (mounted): `drw-r--r-- 2 root bind 4096 apr 30 07:48 zones`

You haven't given anyone the *execute/traverse* (`+x`) permission on the parent directory. Without it, users can only read the file names but are not allowed to actually access anything inside.

Use `chmod a+x /etc/bind/zones` to fix this.